# Represent electric circuit with loops, flows in XML format?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, xsd

Does anyone knows, how to represent a complex electric circuit with loops, flows in XML format?

The efficient way to parse it?

Efficient data structure to store parsing data, from which we can again create XML?

Thank you.

Comment: Somehow I don't think, that `Efficient data structure` and `XML` belong in the same sentence...

Comment: @nfechner That's a matter of opinion more than anything else. XML just provides syntax for conjuring up markup languages. How you use it is entirely up to you. XML is good for interoperability, great tool support and clarity. It's not something you'll want to process in an embedded system with 1 MiB memory. "Efficient" is not a synonym for "small" or "not verbose" in every context.

Comment: Some kind of a [netlist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlist) maybe. What are loops and flows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are standard XML parsers (e.g. DOM for in-memory and SAX for event-based processing) that you should be using.

You can represent a circuit in XML pretty easily - it's nothing more than nodes and connectors of different types.  Write a schema that represents them.

I'm picturing something simple, like this one for a serial RC circuit:

```
<circuit>
    <node id="1"/>
    <node id="2"/>
    <node id="3"/>
    <connector id="1" type="resistor" value="10" units="ohm">
        <start-node>1</start-node>
        <end-node>2</start-node>
    </connector>
    <connector id="2" type="capacitor" value="10" units="farad">
        <start-node>2</start-node>
        <end-node>3</start-node>
    </connector>
    <connector id="3" type="battery" value="10" units="volts">
        <start-node>3</start-node>
        <end-node>1</start-node>
    </connector>
</circuit>
```

Comment: Or even better than DOM and SAX, use the schema with XJC to generate JAXB classes which naturally represent the defined constructs.

Comment: Thank you for example and for your answers.